What's a word for an operation or protocol that doesn't really matter but is done out of habit, tradition, or law, ceremonial, perfunctory?
I'm looking for a word to describe an action, such as a vote by the board, that's required, but not meaningful because the issue is already settled, or the vote cannot but go a particular way. Just for show. Ceremonial. Something like that.

The proceedings were meaningless, just a _____.


Depending on the context, it might be either a "formality" or a "shibboleth".

There's also "rubber stamp".

'Meaningless ritual' is a relevant fixed phrase. Power Thesaurus only offers mulii-word synonyms.

'de rigueur', or 'going through the motions'.

'Mulii' is a typo, not a protologism.

Ceremonial and perfunctory are good, too.  Especially ceremonial.

Ooh, I like it's just pro forma, but that's used adjectivially there.

@user888379 For me, "shibboleth" always carries some connotation of adhering to or defining a group identity, as in its origin.

formality is the obvious word to fill the blank.  I don't know why @user888379 thinks shibboleth fits. — From the title I thought you meant ceremonies that formerly had substantive effect; I might call those vestigial.

@AntonSherwood It might be a bit of a stretch but "shibboleth" can have a connotation of "this is how we've always done it" detached from any current utility.

You could call it a formality, defined by AHD as:

An established form, rule, or custom, especially one followed merely for the sake of procedure or decorum.


To insist on the lack of importance of the action, one may say that it was just a mere formality.
